# Is it possible to scrape javascript objects present inside the script tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, screen-scraping

I need to get the value inside this:

```
window.runParams.quantityLimit = {
  isPurchaseLimit: "",
  unit: 'pieces',
  quantityNum: '19 ',
  availQuantityForCustomer: '19'
};
```

I tried parsing the DOM object but I am only able to access HTML or XML objects and not able to fetch the data associated with `quantityNum`

```
function parseData(){
  $("#file").hide();
  var data = storage.getItem(key);  
  var parsed = $.parse(data); 
  $("#unparsed").val(data);
  $("#parsed").val(JSON.stringify(parsed));
}
```

I need to get the value associated with the javascript element `availQuantityForCustomer`, i.e `19` in the above example.

Comment: If that JS code is within a `script` tag in the DOM, then you don't need to scrape it as the value is already accessible. Just use `window.runParams.quantityLimit.quantityNum`. If that's not what you mean please edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: What do you see if you run `console.log(window.runParams)`?